# A loop to write equations to be used with odeint

Tags: python, scipy, odeint

I have an initial value problem that needs to be solved; the differential equations are derived from a dictionary that looks like:

```
eqs = {'a': array([-1.,  2.,  4.,  0., ...]),
 'b': array([  1., -10.,   0.,   0., ...]),
 'c': array([ 0.,  3., -4.,  0., ...]),
 'd': array([ 0.,  5.,  0., -0., ...]),
...}
```

The differential equation `da/dt` is given as `-1*[a]+2*[b]+4*[c]+0*[d]`....

Using the dictionary above, I write a function `dXdt` as:

```
def dXdt (X, t):
    sys_a, sys_b, sys_c, sys_d,... = eqs['a'], eqs['b'], eqs['c'], eqs['d'],...
    dadt = sys_a[0]*X[0]+sys_a[1]*X[1]+sys_a[2]*X[2]+sys_a[3]*X[3]+...
    dbdt = sys_b[0]*X[0]+sys_b[1]*X[1]+sys_b[2]*X[2]+sys_b[3]*X[3]+...
    dcdt = sys_c[0]*X[0]+sys_c[1]*X[1]+sys_c[2]*X[2]+sys_c[3]*X[3]+...
    dddt = sys_d[0]*X[0]+sys_d[1]*X[1]+sys_d[2]*X[2]+sys_d[3]*X[3]+...
    ...
    return [dadt, dbdt, dcdt, dddt, ...]
```

The initial conditions are:

```
X0 = [1, 0, 0, 0, ...]
```

and the solution is given as:

```
X = integrate.odeint(dXdt, X0, np.linspace(0,10,11))
```

This works well for a small system, where I can write the equations by hand. However, I have a system that has ~150 differential equations, and I need to automate the way I write `dXdt` to be used `with scipy.integrate.odeint`, given the dictionary of `eqs`. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: _Is there a way to do so?_ Yes, there seems to be a rather obvious pattern in the code. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: @AMC, Could you please show me how? I have been stuck on this for a while now :(

Comment: Have you tried writing pseudocode/an algorithm on paper?

Comment: My major confusion is defining the variables within a for loop, when I don't know the # and name of variables I would need.

Comment: don't use `sys_a` and `dadt` but `eqs["a"]` and `dt["a"]` or `dt[0]` and then you can use `for key in eqs.keys()`  with `eqs[key]` and `dt[key]`

Comment: don't use `result = sys_a[0]*X[0] + ... ` but `for a, x in zip(eqs["a"], X):  result += a*x`

Comment: If you use `numpy.array` for `X` then you could write it `dadt = (X*eqs['a']).sum()`. Or even `dadt = X @ eqs['a']`

Comment: Since the derivative function basically does a matrix multiplication, the idiomatic numpy way would be to turn your `eqs` dict to a 2D-array so that your function simply becomes `def dXdt(X, t): return X @ eqs`.

Comment: @luciole75w This example uses first-order equations, but I will have to add a +k[a][b] type to the equations later on, so I am unable to use exponentiation of matrix method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time something follows a simple linear pattern, you can use an iteration or a comprehension to express it.  If you have multiple such patterns, you can just nest them.  So this:

```
    sys_a, sys_b, sys_c, sys_d,... = eqs['a'], eqs['b'], eqs['c'], eqs['d'],...
    dadt = sys_a[0]*X[0]+sys_a[1]*X[1]+sys_a[2]*X[2]+sys_a[3]*X[3]+...
    dbdt = sys_b[0]*X[0]+sys_b[1]*X[1]+sys_b[2]*X[2]+sys_b[3]*X[3]+...
    dcdt = sys_c[0]*X[0]+sys_c[1]*X[1]+sys_c[2]*X[2]+sys_c[3]*X[3]+...
    dddt = sys_d[0]*X[0]+sys_d[1]*X[1]+sys_d[2]*X[2]+sys_d[3]*X[3]+...
    ...
    [dadt, dbdt, dcdt, dddt, ...]
```

can be expressed simply as:

```
[sum(eqs[char][i] * X[i] for i in range(len(X))) for char in eqs.keys()]
```